# Heroku apex record setup

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, heroku

I have a [heroku application](http://www.ponyfoo.com/) and I want to configure my domain to redirect the apex record to `www.`.

Are there any free services I could use for this purpose?

I mean other than rolling my own solution and hosting it in a free hosting environment that supports `A` records, or using a service like that of [dnsimple](https://dnsimple.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options I've used:

- http://wwwizer.com/
- For $0.50/month, Amazon Route 53 will host DNS on your domain. You can then use Amazon S3's [new root domain support](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/12/27/root-domain-support-on-amazon-s3-hosted-websites/) to redirect to your www subdomain on Heroku.

Comment: `wwwizer.com` did the trick, ty!

Comment: @Nico It works, but do consider the ramifications of relying on a free service for this. They should shut down or do something nasty at any time. I wouldn't use it for a web store, for example.

Comment: of course, but in my case, since it's just a technical blogging application, this will do just fine for the time being